# Stored procedure, pass table name as a parameter

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005

I have about half a dozen generic, but fairly complex stored procedures and functions that I would like to use in a more generic fashion.

Ideally I'd like to be able to pass the table name as a parameter to the procedure, as currently it is hard coded.

The research I have done suggests I need to convert all existing SQL within my procedures to use dynamic SQL in order to splice in the dynamic table name from the parameter, however I was wondering if there is a easier way by referencing the table in another way?

For example:

```
SELECT * FROM @MyTable WHERE...
```

If so, how do I set the @MyTable variable from the table name?

I am using SQL Server 2005.

Comment: How/where are these tables being created or stored? 

Are they results from other queries?

Comment: As marc_s said, upgrade to SQL 2008.  Table-Value parameters are pure awesomeness when dealing with large numbers of updates to a single table.

Comment: Please read his question more closely. Despite the question title, he's trying to pass a table name (not a table).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Dynamic SQL is the only way to do this, but I'd reconsider the architecture of your application if it requires this. SQL isn't very good at "generalized" code. It works best when it's designed and coded to do individual tasks.

Selecting from TableA is not the same as selecting from TableB, even if the select statements look the same. There may be different indexes, different table sizes, data distribution, etc.

You could generate your individual stored procedures, which is a common approach. Have a code generator that creates the various select stored procedures for the tables that you need. Each table would have its own SP(s), which you could then link into your application.

I've written these kinds of generators in T-SQL, but you could easily do it with most programming languages. It's pretty basic stuff.

Just to add one more thing since Scott E brought up ORMs... you should also be able to use these stored procedures with most sophisticated ORMs.

Comment: Can anyone provide more information on writing a SQL generator? How do you deploy, etc. and make sure that all the locations where the generated code is duplicated remain in sync?

Comment: IMO the generated code should all be checked into your source control system. You can then modify them for things that are specific to a particular table, etc. Any deploys that you run should use the files from your source control system. You can use a tool like Red Gate's SQLCompare (and SQLDataCompare) to make sure that various DBs are in sync. They are at www.red-gate.com. They also have a new SQL Source Control product and a deploy packager.

Answer (score 1):

You'd have to use dynamic sql. But don't do that! You're better off using an ORM.

Comment: Adding an ORM would add a very high level of overhead. While you're at it don't use a hammer to put that nail in, I've got this really big boulder you can use.

Comment: I'd take that over the security risks of dynamic sql any day. And for most simple queries, something like linq-to-sql adds little overhead. Also, 'very high level of overhead' is pretty subjective, don't you think? Kind of like saying 'don't use dynamic sql' I guess!

Answer (score 1):

```
EXEC(N'SELECT * from ' + @MyTable + N' WHERE ...     ')
```

Comment: Dynamic SQL isn't usually 'optimal' but don't listen to those who say never to use it. It has it's place.

Answer (score 1):

You can use dynamic Sql, but check that the object exists first unless you can 100% trust the source of that parameter. It's likely that there will be a performance hit as SQL server won't be able to re-use the same execution plan for different parameters.

```
IF OBJECT_ID(@tablename, N'U') IS NOT NULL
BEGIN 
    --dynamic sql
END
```

Answer (score 0):

```
ALTER procedure [dbo].[test](@table_name varchar(max))
 AS
 BEGIN
  declare @tablename varchar(max)=@table_name;
  declare @statement varchar(max);
  set @statement = 'Select * from ' + @tablename;
  execute (@statement);
 END
```