# how to pass tablename as parameter in sql server

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005

hello frnds i need to pass a table name as parameter to stored procedure

```
CREATE PROCEDURE six @tablename nvarchar
AS
SELECT * FROM + @tablename
Go
exec six Entry_sixsigma_mag
```

it gives error like

Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Procedure six, Line 3
Incorrect syntax near '+'.
Msg 208, Level 16, State 1, Procedure six, Line 3
Invalid object name '@sixsigma'.

Comment: Probable duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3346842/stored-procedure-pass-table-name-as-a-parameter

Answer (score 4):

Try something like

```
CREATE PROCEDURE six @tablename nvarchar(100) 
AS 
EXEC('SELECT * FROM ' + @tablename)
Go 
exec six Entry_sixsigma_mag
```

Have a look at [EXECUTE (Transact-SQL)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/execute-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15)

But you should also have a look at

- [SQL Injection](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/sql/sql-server-2008-r2/ms161953%28v=sql.105%29)
- [Dynamic SQL & SQL injection](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/raulga/dynamic-sql-sql-injection)

before using this blindly.

Comment: hey it gives error Msg 208, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
Invalid object name 'E'.

Comment: You need to change nvarchar to nvarchar(100) or what ever your length is you need. You have to remember that if you do not specify the length of a NVARCHAR/VARCHAR it will assume 1.

Comment: Instead of EXEC('...') you can also use sp_executesql: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188001.aspx