# Table variable in a stored procedure

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, stored-procedures

I would like to create a simple stored procedure which take as a parameter existing tables.

I thought this procedure should work:

```
@UserID INT,
@TableName varchar(255)
AS
BEGIN
    IF(@UserID is not null)
    BEGIN
       update t
       set t.ProductID = 100
       from dbo.[@TableName] t

    END
```

When I execute this stored procedure with a table name, the query completed with errors:

> Invalid object name 'dbo.@TableName'.

Any advice?

Comment: you can't do query a dynamic table name like that. Would need to use dynamic TSQL

Comment: Canonical reading on this; http://www.sommarskog.se/dynamic_sql.html

Comment: possible duplicate of [Stored procedure, pass table name as a parameter](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3346842/stored-procedure-pass-table-name-as-a-parameter)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'd have to do something like the following:

```
DECLARE @SQL NVARCHAR(100)
SET @SQL = 'UPDATE ' + @TABLENAME + ' SET t.ProductID = 100 '
EXEC sp_executesql @SQL
```

Note: You have no `WHERE` clause so all items in the `@TableName` will be updated.

Comment: in SQL Server 2008 R2 also  EXEC (@SQL)  works. In what version is sp_executesql necessary?

Comment: @derU - sp_executesql is more efficient and preferred over EXEC.  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-GB/library/ms175170(v=sql.105).aspx